# How do I pass webscraped data into a html table?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to make a webscraper that will get data from coronavirus websites. I have made the scraper I was just curious as to how to pass that data I get to my html code. Here is my pyhton code for the webscraper.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

import csv

from bs4 import NavigableString

from flask import Flask


page_url = 'https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html

uClient = uReq(page_url)

page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")

uClient.close()

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"callout"})

out_filename = "usacovid_deaths.csv"

headers = "Deaths \n"

Deaths = containers[0].span.text

print(Deaths +"\n")

with open(out_filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    spamwriter.writerow([Deaths])

html_file_smth = 'C:\\Users\\tshor\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\HTML\\Stats.html'

html_file_smth2 = 'C:\\Users\\tshor\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\HTML\\Stats2.html'

with open(html_file_smth, 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as htmll:

    reader = htmll.read()

html_content = soup(reader, 'html.parser')

tr_tag = html_content.find(attrs = {"id":"use-id"})

tr_tag.insert(0, NavigableString(str(Deaths)))

with open(html_file_smth2, 'w',encoding="utf-8") as html2:

    html2.write(reader)
```

By the way, I know this type of website has been done before but I still want to do it for my own enjoyment. Also, it says to import flask but I am not sure if that is really what I am looking for. I dont really know I am a beginner at coding. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You are writing the same object reader to the output file. 
You should write parsed data tr_tag into html2, if it gives your correct output.
Is tr_tag printing correctly what you want to get from the site?

Comment: @MoidShaikh I am trying to collect the number of deaths on this site. Also, I'm not really sure what you mean by writing the parsed data to the tr tag. I do get the correct data.